# How to make a Twitter Bootstrap navigation menu highlighted when clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a menu like this:

```html
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner"> 
            <div class="container">               
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="About.php" target="_self">About</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried many scripts to make 'Home' highlighted when 'Home' menu is clicked. I was not able to achieve what I wanted. Pls help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in CSS:

li:active

And then whichever instructions you wish to carry out.